# Can someone help me understand why this is not compiling (Unable to Compile class for JSP: The method is undefined)

Tags: java, jsp

Error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [19] in the jsp file: [/Sid_validator.jsp]
The method checkStudentID(String) is undefined for the type Manager

```
16:     String id = request.getParameter("sid");
17:     String title = "";
18:     boolean redirect = false;
19:     boolean flag = Manager.checkStudentID(id);
20:     if(!flag){
21:         redirect = true;
22:     }
```

Stacktrace:

> org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:461)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
>       org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

JSP:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="source.Manager" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
 <%
 
 String id = request.getParameter("sid");
 String title = "";
 boolean redirect = false;
 boolean flag = Manager.checkStudentID(id);
 if(!flag){
  redirect = true;
 }

 if(redirect){
 %>
  <script>
  alert("You entered an invalid student id, redirecting to homepage...");
  window.location.href = "index.jsp";
  </script>
  
 <%
 }
 else{
  
 }
 %>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```
public static boolean checkStudentID(String id) throws SQLException {
    //Connecting to Database
    connectToDB();

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(CHECK_ID + id + ";");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    return rs.next();
}
```

This is the function I've implemented.  It is written withing the Manager.java class, I have previously tested the method "connectToDB()" also works, and I have also previously called static functions from the Manager class in the JSP. So I do not understand why this is giving me an error.

Comment: Have you recompiled the `Manager` class recently?

Comment: Have you cleaned/restarted everything to make sure that you are using the right version of the compiled Manager?

Comment: No, I'll try doing that now.

Comment: Just to check that everything is ok with your `Manager.class` try to decompile it, for example using this http://www.javadecompilers.com/ and make sure that you have `checkStudentID` method there.

Comment: After trying many things and still not working, I just figured maybe I messed some of the configurations of the project (I hadn't worked on it in a while) so I just created a new Project and started from scratch and everything seems to be working fine...